# Link sass compiles css file in AEM

Tags: aem

HI I'm very new to AEM and working on a project doing the frontend styling. I managed to create a SASS folder with my scss file in it - updated the pom file to compile it to css in the css folder. but what i do not know is how do i link my newly created css file to the project?

Comment: You mean, how to get your CSS on your AEM machine? Or how to build an AEM project in a way that your CSS is included in the resulting package?

Answer (score 0):

Create a clientlib and include your css files in that.
This newly created clientlib should be included in the base page html/jsp or at the component level.

To create a clientlibs for your project, follow below URL.
https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/developing/introduction/clientlibs.html

To include this clientlib in your component/base page, use below code snippet.

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientLib="${'/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html'}">
<!--for css+js -->
<sly data-sly-call="${clientLib.all @ categories='your.clientlib'}</sly>
<!-- only js -->
<sly data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories='your.clientlib'}" ></sly>
<!-- only css -->
<sly data-sly-call="${clientLib.css @ categories='your.clientlib'}" ></sly>
```